# How to make text strikethough in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, strikethrough

Is it possible to make text **<strike>strikethrough</strike>** in the Sphinx documentation generator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've done this.

Require a .CSS in your conf.py

```
html_style = 'mydoc.css'
```

In the `_static/mydoc.css`, use something like this

```
@import url("default.css");

span.strikethrough { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

In the document, do this.

```
 ..  role:: strikethrough

 make text :strikethrough:`strikethrough` in the sphinx
```