# Extra blank lines in a Sphinx unordered list

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing documentation for my project using Sphinx and have found a difference in how two similar reStructuredText segements, given below, are rendered.

#### Example 1

```
Some text:

*  Item 0
*  Item 1
*  Item 2

   ::

       Some code
       Some code
       Some code
       Some code

   .. WARNING::
      Some text.

*  Item 3
```

#### Example 2

```
Some inline text:

*  Item 0
*  Item 1
*  Item 2

  ::                           <-- One less space before the :: marker

       Some code
       Some code
       Some code
       Some code

  .. WARNING::                 <-- One less space before the .. marker
      Some warning text.

*  Item 3
```

Example 1 is producing additional whitespace between list items `Item 0`, `Item 1` and `Item 2`, but the second example renders without this additional spacing. See the final markup of [example 1](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=3fcba096533ea192a9ab83675a6c57d8&theme=basic) and [example 2](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=ba863b6ed7f2edc7ba4b1a0728c8e354&theme=basic). This only happens with the "basic" theme.

Why do I have to follow my second example then if I don't want the additional spacing produced by example 1?

Comment: You have two spaces between the list marker and the list item text. Try using `* Item 0`, not `*  Item 0`. It would be useful to have screen shots of the output from using both reStructuredText extracts and an indication of what you were expecting and why the output is not what you want ("render the list well" is not a particularly useful description). Finally, I would have written `* Item 2::` (no line break between `Item 2` and the `::`, why do you have `::` on a line by itself?

Comment: @Chris, here is [example 1](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=3fcba096533ea192a9ab83675a6c57d8&theme=basic) and here is [example 2](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=ba863b6ed7f2edc7ba4b1a0728c8e354&theme=basic). I like to give unordered list items 2 spaces after the bullet (so they're indented as much as ordered lists), plus it doesn't alter the rendering. And about the lone `::`, the 2 ways aren't getting me any differences and I liked this one.

Comment: @Chris, when I say those things aren't altering the rendering, it is wrong. It wasn't making any difference until I was on this particular case, where it makes my render looks like example 1. Also please use the *Basic* theme, as the *Nature* theme doesn't show the issue I am facing.

Comment: The difference you are seeing in the spacing of the list items is just a CSS styling issue for one of the themes on the site you link to. There is a difference is semantics between the two examples you give however: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it seems that the issue is with the rendering of reStructuredText on http://rst.ninjs.org and how this looks with one particular CSS theme. This is not really an issue with reStructuredText.

Ignoring the styling issues, the reason you are seeing two different behaviours between the two examples is because the two examples are different: in the first the code block is part of list item `Item 2`; in the second example the code block is *not*, and therefore closes the list above it and `Item 3` therefore starts a new list.

We can see why from studying the [reStructuredText specification on bullet lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists) (emphasis mine),

> A text block which begins with a "*", "+", "-", "•", "‣", or "⁃", followed by whitespace, is a bullet list item (a.k.a. "unordered" list item). List item bodies must be left-aligned and indented relative to the bullet; **the text immediately after the bullet determines the indentation.**

In your first example the `::` is aligned with the start of the text bullet list item, and so is part of the list item body. In the second example the `::` is not at the same level of identation as the list item text and so closes the list and begins a code block (which is *not* a child of the list item). This is obvious if we compare the HTML produced by [example 1](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/?text=Some+text%3A%0A%0A%2a++List+item+0%0A%2a++List+item+1%0A%2a++List+item+2%3A%0A%0A+++%3A%3A%0A%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A%0A+++..+WARNING%3A%3A%0A++++++Some+warning+text.%0A%0A%2a++List+item+3%0A%2a++List+item+4%0A%0A+++%23.+List+item+a%0A+++%23.+List+item+b%0A+++%23.+List+item+c%0A+++%23.+List+item+d%0A%0A..+NOTE%3A%3A%0A+++Some+note+text.%0A&from=rst&to=html) and [example 2](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/?text=Some+text%3A%0A%0A%2a++List+item+0%0A%2a++List+item+1%0A%2a++List+item+2%3A%0A%0A++%3A%3A%0A%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A+++++++Some+code+text%0A%0A++..+WARNING%3A%3A%0A++++++Some+warning+text.%0A%0A%2a++List+item+3%0A%2a++List+item+4%0A%0A+++%23.+List+item+a%0A+++%23.+List+item+b%0A+++%23.+List+item+c%0A+++%23.+List+item+d%0A%0A..+NOTE%3A%3A%0A+++Some+note+text.%0A&from=rst&to=html).

The take away point is that the start of the text in a list item defines the level of indentation which you must match if you want to add to the body of that list item.

Comment: I guess I gave too much significance to the front versus the back, I should have inspect the rendered HTML. You are right indeed, using ordered list (instead of unordered) showed me that there were actually 2 different lists in the example 2. Now there is an other thing I don't get, in this updated [example 1](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=05b297b1075324d00b207a3fba8d3c75&theme=basic), I added a second unordered list. In the first list, every item is enclosed into a `<p>` tag while in the second list, items are directly inside the `<li>` tag.

Comment: I don't see what you mention on [johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/?text=Some+text%3A%0A%0A*+List+item+0%0A*+List+item+1%0A*+List+item+2%3A%3A%0A%0A++++++Some+code+text%0A++++++Some+code+text%0A++++++Some+code+text%0A++++++Some+code+text%0A%0A++..+WARNING%3A%3A%0A+++++Some+warning+text.%0A%0A*+List+item+3%0A*+List+item+4%0A%0A++%23.+List+item+a%0A++%23.+List+item+b%0A++%23.+List+item+c%0A++%23.+List+item+d%0A%0A*+List+item+5%0A%0AThis+text+is+here+to+end+the+list.%0A%0A*+foo%0A*+bar%0A*+foobar%0A&from=rst&to=html), only `Item 2` has a paragraph tag.

Comment: I understand, but my Sphinx documentation has the exact same behavior as in rst.ninjs.org. What do you advice me to do (beside hacking the theme CSS) ?

Comment: If you don't like the default styling provided by Sphinx I am afraid that you will have to edit the CSS. Don't start writing unsemantic reStructuredText just to adjust how the text is rendered, that will probably lead to all sorts of problems, not least with maintainability. Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4410376/623518) for how to add custom CSS styles - just add a rule to overwrite the default padding/margin of `li` elements. If you need help doing this I would ask a new question.

Comment: This is definitely not a proper behavior (as a the `first` class is applied to each of the list element). I got it to *work* by following your last comment with `margin: 0 !important;` for the `first `class`.

Comment: This answer may be correct but does not answer the real question of why there are extra `<p>` tags resulting in extra spacing. The same code from the pandoc example does produce extra `<p class="first">` inside the `<li>` for List Item 0-5, so maybe a bug in docutils?